# How to get json response from aiohttp?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, aiohttp

how to get json response from aiohttp?
if i use .json() i getting the error:

> File "main.py", line 371, in _checker
> user_name = f'{res_json["username"]}#{res_json["discriminator"]}'

TypeError: 'coroutine' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.json()` [returns a coroutine](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#coroutines), hence you need to [`await` the `response.json()` to actually run the coroutine](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_quickstart.html#json-response-content)

```
async with session.get('https://api.github.com/events') as resp:
    print(await resp.json())
          ^^^^^
```